# Can some one give an example of the HTML table that needs to build to utilize HighChart Large tree map

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am utilizing the Highchart standalone-framework.js and generating HTML Tables and then using the HTML tables as data sources.  I have a tree Map in mind where I would like to use the Large tree map(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/treemap-large-dataset).

Can anyone give an example of what a HTML table should look like for the example provided on (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/treemap-large-dataset)?

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of problem do you come across? The table can be any, only what you need is create a parser which iterate on each element in table and push that in series object keeping right format.

Comment: I am having trouble visualizing it, since it seems like each layer of the tree map is a different table in it self.  Will this be a html table of html tables?